# Multi-level function templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to process vectors in a generic way with C++14. I have the following code, simplified from my real example (I know this can be done with std stuff, my real example is multithreaded and much more complex):

```
#include <vector>

// there will be lots of these
struct add1_op {
  static inline void doit(float x0, float& dst) {
    dst = x0 + 1;
  }
};

// there will be multiples of these with different args
template<class Op>
void process_vec1(const std::vector<float> src, std::vector<float> dst)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
    Op::doit(src[i], dst[i]);
  }
}

using Proc_v1_to_v1 = void (*)(const std::vector<float>, std::vector<float>);

template<typename Processor> // NOTE: works with <Proc_v1_to_v1 Processor>
void dispatch(const std::vector<float> src, std::vector<float> dst, int mode)
{
  if (mode == 0)
    Processor(src, dst);
  // ... other modes ...
}

void add1_vec(const std::vector<float> src, std::vector<float> dst, int mode)
{
  dispatch<process_vec1<add1_op> >(src, dst, mode);
}
```

This doesn't compile with clang on MacOS: gets `error: no matching function for call to 'dispatch'`, saying `foo.cxx:28:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Processor'`

If I replace `typename Processor` with the actual typename `Proc_v1_to_v1`, it works. But I don't see why the compiler shouldn't be able to deduce the type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be confusing a type with a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template argument deduction occurs when you pass a **function argument** that has a type specified by the **template parameter**:

```
template<typename Processor>
void dispatch(Processor processor, const std::vector<float> src, std::vector<float> dst, int mode);

dispatch(process_vec1<add1_op>, src, dst, mode);
```

In your case, however, you are passing a pointer to a function `process_vec1<add1_op>` (which is a **value**) as an argument for template parameter `Processor` which is a **type**. And this is what the error is about: a value is a wrong argument for a type parameter.

If you really want to use template parameter to specify a function you could:

- Make `Processor` a non-type template parameter like you did with `Proc_v1_to_v1`
- Or make `process_vec1` into a functor the way Yakk suggested in his answer.

Comment: Aha, the light dawns. Thanks. The name of a function is a pointer to that function; the name of a class is a type. (Not always but in my case here.) For posterity, or as long as this gist lasts, here's the working functor version as a combination of Yakk's answer and this one: https://gist.github.com/garyo/438c47e48a7d1efddce068dd717aa1b5

Comment: I'm marking this answer as accepted because it explains my error so clearly, although Yakk's contribution is just as important.

Answer (score 1):

Use stateless function objects.

```
struct add1_op {
  void operator()(float x0, float& dst) const {
    dst = x0 + 1;
  }
};

template<class Op>
struct process_vec1{
  void operator()(const std::vector<float> src, std::vector<float> dst) const {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
      Op{}(src[i], dst[i]);
    }
  }
};
```